# Modifying the code so that it can read from a file, and produce corresponding outputs

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, bioinformatics

I am trying to modify the below program as follows:

1. The first line contains the name of the protein and the count of subsequent lines of output for this protein (say N)
2. Each of the next N lines contains a match information: the locations of the GBoxes and the actual matches (remember there are perturbations and X's, i.e. wild cards, that are allowed).

Script:

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# all G boxes
def match(x,y):
        mismatch = 0
        for i in range(len(x)):
                if (x[i] == 'X' or x[i] == y[i]):
                        pass
                else:
                        mismatch += 1
        if(mismatch <= 1):
                return True
        else:
                return False



def H(protein,x1,x2,x3,x4):
        pL1=[]
        pL2=[]
        pL3=[]
        pL4=[]
        L1=[]
        L2=[]
        L3=[]
        L4=[]


        for i in range(len(protein)-len(x1)):
                if(match(x1, protein[i:i+len(x1)]) == True):
#                       global L1
                        pL1=pL1 + [i]
                        L1 = L1+[protein[i:i+len(x1)]]


        for j in range(len(protein)-len(x2)):
                if (match(x2, protein[j:j+len(x2)]) == True):
#                       global L2
                        pL2=pL2+[j]
                        L2 = L2+[protein[j:j+len(x2)]]

        for k in range(len(protein)-len(x3)):
                if (match(x3, protein[k:k+len(x3)]) == True):
 #                           global L3
                        pL3=pL3+[k]
                        L3 = L3+[protein[k:k+len(x3)]]

        for l in range(len(protein)-len(x4)):
                if (match(x4, protein[l:l+len(x4)]) == True):
#                       global L3
                        pL4=pL4+[l]
                        L4 = L4+[protein[l:l+len(x4)]]
        candidates = []

        for i in range(len(pL1)):
                for j in range(len(pL2)):
                        for k in range(len(pL3)):
                                for l in range(len(pL4)):
                                        if 40 <=pL2[j]-pL1[i]  <= 80 and 40 <=pL3[k]- pL2[j] <= 80 and 20 <=pL4[l]- pL3[k] <= 40:
                                                a = L1[i],pL1[i]
                                                b = L2[j],pL2[j]
                                                c = L3[k],pL3[k]
                                                d = L4[l],pL4[l]
                                                print a,b,c,d
                                                candidates.append((a,b,c,d))


        offset = 5
        for i in np.arange((np.array(candidates).transpose()).shape[1]):
                barchartdata = np.unique(np.array(candidates).transpose()[:,i])
                barchartdata = barchartdata.reshape(2, len(barchartdata)/2)
                print barchartdata
                x_pos = np.arange(barchartdata.size/2)
                print x_pos
                print barchartdata[0,:]
                plt.bar(x_pos + 5 * i, barchartdata[0,:])

        plt.show()
        plt.xticks(x_pos, ('g1','g2','g3','g4'))
        plt.yticks('Count')
        plt.show()

x1 = 'GXXXXGK'
x2 = 'DXXG'
x3 = 'NKXD'
x4 =  'EXSAX'
#input sequence 
protein = 'MAKGEFIRTKPHVNVGTIGHVDHGKTTLTAALTYVAAAENPNVEVKDYGEIDKAPEERARGITINTAHVEYETAKRHYSHVDCPGHADYIKNMITGAAQMDGAILVVSAADGPMPQTREHILLARQVGVPYIVVFMNKVDMVDDPELLDLVEMEVRDLLNQYEFPGDEVPVIRGSALLALEQMHRNPKTRRGENEWVDKIWELLDAIDEYIPTPVRDVDKPFLMPVEDVFTITGRGTVATGRIERGKVKVGDEVEIVGLAPETRKTVVTGVEMHRKTLQEGIAGDNVGVLLRGVSREEVERGQVLAKPGSITPHTKFEASVYVLKKEEGGRHTGFFSGYRPQFYFRTTDVTGVVQLPPGVEMVMPGDNVTFTVELIKPVALEEGLRFAIREGGRTVGAGVVTKILE'
H(protein,x1,x2,x3,x4)
```

***Edit***

Previous Output (My Script) - Correct:

```
('GAGGVGK', 9) ('DILD', 53) ('NKCD', 115) ('ETSAK', 142)
('GAGGVGK', 9) ('DTAG', 56) ('NKCD', 115) ('ETSAK', 142)
('GAGGVGK', 9) ('DQYM', 68) ('NKCD', 115) ('ETSAK', 142)
('GAGGVGK', 9) ('MRTG', 71) ('NKCD', 115) ('ETSAK', 142)
('GAGGVGK', 9) ('TGEG', 73) ('NKCD', 115) ('ETSAK', 142)
```

Getting Output in your script:

```
((17, 'GAGGVGK'), (61, 'DILD'), (123, 'NKCD'), (150, 'ETSAK'))
((17, 'GAGGVGK'), (64, 'DTAG'), (123, 'NKCD'), (150, 'ETSAK'))
((17, 'GAGGVGK'), (76, 'DQYM'), (123, 'NKCD'), (150, 'ETSAK'))
((17, 'GAGGVGK'), (79, 'MRTG'), (123, 'NKCD'), (150, 'ETSAK'))
((17, 'GAGGVGK'), (81, 'TGEG'), (123, 'NKCD'), (150, 'ETSAK'))
```

Here is length is the incorrect. 
I need to run for multiple sequence but its running only for one sequence. Please guide me

I also trying to plot a graph but its not able to get expected output.

Expected graph:

In this image is the expected graph - we need to calculate the percentage column wise - please check 'Previous Output (My Script) - Correct: please check below image for example.

[Expected graph image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFSx2.jpg)

***Edit 1***

Input file is a CSV file has following format (multiple rows):

```
PDB ID  Macromolecule Name  Sequence    Source
121P    H-RAS P21 PROTEIN   MTEYKLVVVGAGGVGKSALTIQLIQNHFVDEYDPTIEDSYRKQVVIDGETCLLDILDTAGQEEYSAMRDQYMRTGEGFLCVFAINNTKSFEDIHQYREQIKRVKDSDDVPMVLVGNKCDLAARTVESRQAQDLARSYGIPYIETSAKTRQGVEDAFYTLVREIRQH  Homo sapiens
1A12    REGULATOR OF CHROMOSOME CONDENSATION 1  RRSPPADAIPKSKKVKVSHRSHSTEPGLVLTLGQGDVGQLGLGENVMERKKPALVSIPEDVVQAEAGGMHTVCLSKSGQVYSFGCNDEGALGRDTSVEGSEMVPGKVELQEKVVQVSAGDSHTAALTDDGRVFLWGSFRDNNGVIGLLEPMKKSMVPVQVQLDVPVVKVASGNDHLVMLTADGDLYTLGCGEQGQLGRVPELFANRGGRQGLERLLVPKCVMLKSRGSRGHVRFQDAFCGAYFTFAISHEGHVYGFGLSNYHQLGTPGTESCFIPQNLTSFKNSTKSWVGFSGGQHHTVCMDSEGKAYSLGRAEYGRLGLGEGAEEKSIPTLISRLPAVSSVACGASVGYAVTKDGRVFAWGMGTNYQLGTGQDEDAWSPVEMMGKQLENRVVLSVSSGGQHTVLLVKDKEQS   Homo sapiens
1A2B    TRANSFORMING PROTEIN RHOA   SMAAIRKKLVIVGDVACGKTCLLIVFSKDQFPEVYVPTVFENYVADIEVDGKQVELALWDTAGQEDYDRLRPLSYPDTDVILMCFSIDSPDSLENIPEKWTPEVKHFCPNVPIILVGNKKDLRNDEHTRRELAKMKQEPVKPEEGRDMANRIGAFGYMECSAKTKDGVREVFEMATRAALQA  Homo sapiens
1A2K    NUCLEAR TRANSPORT FACTOR 2  MGDKPIWEQIGSSFIQHYYQLFDNDRTQLGAIYIDASCLTWEGQQFQGKAAIVEKLSSLPFQKIQHSITAQDHQPTPDSCIISMVVGQLKADEDPIMGFHQMFLLKNINDAWVCTNDMFRLALHNFG Rattus norvegicus
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is very unwieldy. I have rewritten it to clean it up a bit. I have removed all the background information about what I chose to change and why, as there was simply too much of it. However, here are some of the things I fixed:

- You have a tendency of writing unpythonic loops in the style

  ```
  for i in range(len(x)):
      do_something_with(x[i])
  ```

  In Python it is much better to write

  ```
  for element in x:
      do_something_with(element)
  ```
- You had lots of superfluous parentheses around `if`-conditions
- You had rewritten essentially the same big `for`-loop four times rather than writing a function containing the loop and reusing it.

Unfortunately the `20` which breaks the pattern established by the `40`s in the quadruply-nested `for`-loop, made replacing it with a single loop over `itertools.product` a bit more trouble than it was worth.

Anyway, here is the cleaned up version of the code.

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def match(X,Y):
        mismatch = 0
        for x,y in zip(X,Y):
                if not (x == 'X' or x == y):
                        mismatch += 1
                        if mismatch > 1:
                            return False
        return True

def H(protein,x1,x2,x3,x4):

        def find_matches(x):
            match_positions = []
            matches         = []
            for i in range(len(protein) - len(x)):
                candidate = protein[i : i + len(x)]
                if match(x, candidate):
                    match_positions.append(i)
                    matches        .append(candidate)
            return matches, match_positions

        L1, pL1 = find_matches(x1)
        L2, pL2 = find_matches(x2)
        L3, pL3 = find_matches(x3)
        L4, pL4 = find_matches(x4)

        candidates = []
        for a in zip(pL1, L1):
            for b in zip(pL2, L2):
                for c in zip(pL3, L3):
                    for d in zip(pL4, L4):
                        if (40 <= b[0] - a[0] <= 80 and
                            40 <= c[0] - b[0] <= 80 and
                            20 <= d[0] - c[0] <= 80    ):
                            print(a,b,c,d)
                            candidates.append((a,b,c,d))

        for i in np.arange((np.array(candidates).transpose()).shape[1]):
                barchartdata = np.unique(np.array(candidates).transpose()[:,i])
                barchartdata = barchartdata.reshape(2, len(barchartdata)//2)
                print (barchartdata)
                x_pos = np.arange(barchartdata.size/2)
                print (x_pos)
                print (barchartdata[0,:])
                plt.bar(x_pos + 5 * i, barchartdata[0,:])

        plt.show()
        plt.xticks(x_pos, ('g1','g2','g3','g4'))
        plt.yticks('Count')
        plt.show()

x1 = 'GXXXXGK'
x2 = 'DXXG'
x3 = 'NKXD'
x4 = 'EXSAX'

protein = 'MAKGEFIRTKPHVNVGTIGHVDHGKTTLTAALTYVAAAENPNVEVKDYGEIDKAPEERARGITINTAHVEYETAKRHYSHVDCPGHADYIKNMITGAAQMDGAILVVSAADGPMPQTREHILLARQVGVPYIVVFMNKVDMVDDPELLDLVEMEVRDLLNQYEFPGDEVPVIRGSALLALEQMHRNPKTRRGENEWVDKIWELLDAIDEYIPTPVRDVDKPFLMPVEDVFTITGRGTVATGRIERGKVKVGDEVEIVGLAPETRKTVVTGVEMHRKTLQEGIAGDNVGVLLRGVSREEVERGQVLAKPGSITPHTKFEASVYVLKKEEGGRHTGFFSGYRPQFYFRTTDVTGVVQLPPGVEMVMPGDNVTFTVELIKPVALEEGLRFAIREGGRTVGAGVVTKILE'
H(protein,x1,x2,x3,x4)
```

**When I execute this above code I get the output**

```
((3, 'GEFIRTK'), (57, 'RARG'), (136, 'NKVD'), (172, 'RGSAL'))
((3, 'GEFIRTK'), (81, 'DCPG'), (136, 'NKVD'), (172, 'RGSAL'))
((18, 'GHVDHGK'), (81, 'DCPG'), (136, 'NKVD'), (172, 'RGSAL'))
((18, 'GHVDHGK'), (87, 'DYIK'), (136, 'NKVD'), (172, 'RGSAL'))
((18, 'GHVDHGK'), (92, 'MITG'), (136, 'NKVD'), (172, 'RGSAL'))
```

**When I execute the code which is visible in your question at the time of writing, I get the output**

```
('GEFIRTK', 3) ('RARG', 57) ('NKVD', 136) ('RGSAL', 172)
('GEFIRTK', 3) ('DCPG', 81) ('NKVD', 136) ('RGSAL', 172)
('GHVDHGK', 18) ('DCPG', 81) ('NKVD', 136) ('RGSAL', 172)
('GHVDHGK', 18) ('DYIK', 87) ('NKVD', 136) ('RGSAL', 172)
('GHVDHGK', 18) ('MITG', 92) ('NKVD', 136) ('RGSAL', 172)
```

Are you ablosutely sure that you ran the two codes over **the same data**? Do note that your code is using the `protein` which is hard-wired into the code, while my code **was** using the data you have in the sample CSV file content. The former starts with 'MAKG', the latter starts with 'MTEY'. These are not the same data, so you would expect them to give different results!

Note that the edited version of the code I have shown above has reverted to using the hard-wired `protein` it the code itself, and **gives identical results to yours**

Here is a code sample that shows how to read your protein data from the CSV file:

```
with open('xxx.csv') as infile:
    lines = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
    next(lines) # skip header
    for line in lines:
        protein = line[4]
        # Do whatever you want with protein here ...
```

Comment: Thanks, Can you please suggest me how to add a CSV file as a input sequence? In input file there is no of protein sequence. I want to run for all sequence

Comment: @vishnu I have edited the answer, to include an answer to what I guess your question might have meant. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you so much, but noot getting right result. i have edited my question please check once

Comment: @vishnu My code gives the same results as yours. Please check again, making sure that **you use the same data in both**. See my latest edit for details.

Comment: Sir, I am getting correct result while running program only for one `prorain` but when using `CSV` file as input (No of sequence).. Please check above `edit 1` for input file format. There is third column sequence. This column we are using as `protein = ........` please help me to solve...and also give your suggestion about the graph... i have attached a image above please check.. thank you

Comment: @vishnu **I** am trying to empower you so that you become able to write this kind of code for yourself. I get the impression that **you** simply want me to do your work for you. That is not the point of this site. I will put back the example code showing you how to read the CSV. After that, it's up to **you** to think about how you can apply the knowledge to **your** problem.

Comment: Thank you sir.... actually i am new in python and that work is important. its ok i will try to do... I requested for help only due to deadline ... I am keep learning python but taking time for this work.. at least guide me how to become python exert like you can do anything? if possible

Comment: @vishnu In general, try to break down your problem, and the questions you ask here, into small, digestible and preferably self-contained components. In this question you have mostly pasted dozens of lines of code and effectively said "It doesn't work, please fix it for me". The easier your question is to understand, the more people will be willing to help you. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and, above all, don't expect people to put more effort into answering your question than you put into preparing and adjusting it.